# Why isn't my input stream opening my file? C++

Tags: c++

I'm reading in a file name from the keyboard and opening the specified file. However it is not meeting my if statement that determines if it's open or not. Heres my code:

```
#include "prog.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string fileName;
cout << "Enter the file name to be read: ";
cin >> fileName;
ifstream input_file("fileName");
std::string line_; // string which text file contents will be stored in

if(input_file.is_open()){ // validation to see if the file is open
  while(getline(input_file, line_)){
    std::cout<<line_<< '\n'; //prints the contents of the file into the console
}
input_file.close();
}
else {
  std::cout<<"File is not open"<< '\n';
}

std::cin.get();
```

After being compiled, I type in the file name I want to open and I get back the else message "File is not open", although the ifstream should of opened it. I definitely have the right file I'm trying to open in the correct folder. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Most likely because you don't have a file called `fileName`? Maybe you meant to write `fileName` instead of `"fileName"`?

Comment: give absolute path to file as parameter

Comment: The keyboard input is the fileName variable, (the file I want to open)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Write that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @LC12382:  You read input into a variable called `fileName`.  Then regardless of what you typed at the keyboard, you open a file whose name is the string of characters f, i, l, e, N, a, m, and e.  Remove the double quotes from around the argument to ifstream constructor.

Comment: nice explanation @MartinBonner thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
ifstream input_file("fileName");
```

to

```
ifstream input_file(fileName);
```

Comment: ... and get an editor that colours string literals in a garish colour.